# @placeholder or placeholder attribute was not change by jquery for MVC textboxfor

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

When I try to change `placeholder` attribute for an `input` element it is successfully done. If I change it to `textboxfor` or `textareafor` element in MVC even if I use `@placeholder` or only `placeholder` it is not working. Here is blocks that I use

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" value="" placeholder="Email"/>
 </div>
```

This attribute changes with this function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#change").click(function () {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ChangeCulture", "Home")',
                data: { cultureCode: $('#change').text() },
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;          
                    $("#person").attr("placeholder", data.Name);
                    $("#mail").attr("placeholder", data.Email);
                    $("#subject").attr("placeholder", data.Matter);
                    $("#message").attr("placeholder", data.Detail);
                },   
            });   
        });
    });
```

And here is the problem. This function does not change `textboxfor` `placeholder` attribute.

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "error" })
 </div>
```

jQuery version is 3.1.1 and MVC version is 5.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you don't specify an `id` attribute for the element, it will take the name of the property of the provided model, hence you need to use `$('#Email')`, not `$('#mail')`, in your jQuery code.

Alternatively, you can provide an `id` in the `TextBoxFor` options:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @id = "mail", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" })
```